# ssh to another machine using while loop

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I have tried to ssh to multiple vms. I used for loop. I want to fetch the username and IP and loop into multiple VMs.

```
export IFS=","
for read f1 f2 in $(cat sample.txt);
do sshpass -p 'password' ssh $f1@$f2 "uname -a" ;
done
```

sample.txt contains

abc,111.111.111.111

def,111.222.333.444

Looks like I am facing an error,
syntax error near unexpected token `f1'`
for read f1 f2 in $(cat LNodeInput.txt);'
I have tried it in few other ways too but still throws an error.

Comment: `for` doesn't work that way, change to `while` and you'll be very close. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS="," read -r f1 f2
do
 sshpass -p 'password' ssh "$f1@$f2" "uname -a" < /dev/null ;
done < sample.txt
```

be careful `sample.txt` should have the last line as empty line, otherwise it will not read the last line of it.

**EDIT:**

`< /dev/null` is to stop ssh from "eating" input from `sample.txt`. Otherwise, the command will only `ssh` to the first server.

Comment: It works!! but it displays the uname of the first IP, am not sure why does it display the output of the next IP. Any suggestions? @user8470034

Comment: @Anna sorry, I didn't get what you mean. you mean it only display one result?

Comment: if that is the case, is that your file only have 2 records? do you have an extra empty line at the end of the `sample.txt` file? pls be careful about that(as I mentioned in my answer)

Comment: Yes, I have added the empty line. Yes, it displays only one result - uname of the first IP and not the second one. To be extra sure I tried it manually and it worked. The code seems not to pick up the IP of the next machine.

Comment: Yes understood!But facing Permission denied, please try again later.Tested it manually and it worked

Comment: @Anna pls use my new answer above, the reason of `< /dev/null` is here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107800/using-while-loop-to-ssh-to-multiple-servers

Comment: @Anna which command do you use? `&& exit` or `</dev/null`? is it really working? I tested on my side, `</dev/null` will work fine. And have the permission denied issue solved?

Comment: I have tested both :&& exit or </dev/null, Still facing ,

Comment: I have tested both: && exit or </dev/null, Still facing while running the script
Permission denied, please try again.
Manually it works. @ user8470034

Comment: @Anna `Manually` you mean you put the whole loop command in terminal instead of in script?

Comment: sshpass -p 'password' ssh testuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx uname -a && exit 
Linux ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal"uanme is displayed here"
logout
There are stopped jobs.
--------------------------
I mean, I do not face permission issues while I log in to this.
Also tired with </dev/null..no permission issue faced
I gave the command in the machine directly

Comment: @Anna what if you copy the whole loop to terminal and press enter?

Comment: Yes tried it!
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Facing the same issue.

Comment: @Anna `sshpass -p 'password' ssh testuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "uname -a && exit" `

will work

`while read ip; echo $ip;do sshpass -p 'password' ssh testuser@$ip "uname -a && exit"; done < ips.txt`

will not work?
Sounds strange to me. 
can you just create the ips.txt with only 1 ip and try? whether there is 1. permission error; 2 uname; 3.permission error+uname; in the output? Sorry the bug is so strange, I want to debug step by step

Answer (score 0):

```
for a in `cat servers`;do echo ;echo $a ; sshpass -p 'password'  ssh $a uname ; done
```

Like this what ever u want u can add before done.. If u want an output collected in a file add > file1 at the end